# JavaScript Pure function

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if this is a pure javascript function.
if it is not I would like to understand the reason.

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array1) { 
  let array2 = [];
  for (let i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    array2.push(array1[i]);
  }
  return array2;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is. I'm not even sure why you'd be asking. If you know what pure function is, it should be pretty clear - no outside data is used and the function will predictably produce the exact same data any time you call it with the same input.

Comment: Function name is very misleading. `reverseArrayInPlace`?

Comment: @BenCoupe that's not really the definition of "pure". It basically has to be referentially transparent. Whether or not it imports anything is irrelevant.

Comment: @BenCoupe that definition of pure functions is purely wrong.

Comment: You're wondering why this one exists, and why the original programmer didn't just use `Array.reverse()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: ah, i kinda assumed what pure meant, i just based it hearing "pure js website" being one that only uses base js and nothing else

Comment: @BenCoupe [no, it's a proper term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: @VLAZ I'm studying right now the pure functions from the eloquent javascript book, an exercise asked me to create a pure function to reverse an array, only I do not understand the solution that adopts the book, it seems more complex than mine. if you want to see the exercise of the book you can find it here: eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.2

Comment: @FrancescoCasella the exercise doesn't specify to use a pure function. And indeed, it's *impossible* to use a pure function for `reverseArrayInPlace` because it should mutate its input and this is impure. As for what the `reverseArrayInPlace` does - it swaps the first and last element, then second and second to last, etc until it reaches the middle. You are showing an implementation for `reverseArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a pure function must produce the same output given the same input, without side effects, your code is pure (assuming that the `array1` parameter will be a plain array, and not something strange like an object with a setter on its `length` property).

That said, purity is generally an issue to be concerned about in functional contexts, and this is not a *functional* approach since you're using `.push`, which mutates the array that you created. A more functional approach would be to use `.map` to create the array to be returned all in one go, without mutation:

```
const reverseArray = (arr) => {
  const { length } = arr;
  return arr.map((_, i) => arr[length - 1]);
};
```

or `Array.from`:

```
const reverseArray = (arr) => {
  const { length } = arr;
  return Array.from(
    arr,
    (_, i) => arr[length - 1]
  );
};
```

Also note that all of these implementations return a *new array*, but they don't reverse the array *in place*. (Any function which reversed the array in-place would be impure, because that would be a side-effect.) Best to either choose a different name than `reverseArrayInPlace`, or, if you do want to reverse the array in-place, give up on purity, since it'd be impossible.

Comment: thank you for your clear and detailed answer! 
the name of the function comes from an exercise of the book eloquent javascript, asked to create a pure function to reverse an array, only I do not understand the solution that adopts the book, it seems more complex than mine. if you want to see the exercise of the book you can find it here:  https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.2

Comment: It's asking you to write *two* functions - one impure one to replace the array in-place, and one which returns a new array (which may be pure).